# Which are the largest LEGO ships that actually float?

Tags: size, boat

My kids are frantic about LEGO ships, and I was wondering which are largest ships ever made.

Of course, they need to be actually able to float in a pool.

Answer (score 6):

The largest LEGO ship that officially floats in water is the Cargo Ship that comes in [7994-1 LEGO City Harbor](https://brickset.com/sets/7994-1/LEGO-City-Harbour):

[image: 7994-1 LEGO City Harbor set image]

It is the only set which contains the [74 x 18 x 7 Boat Hull](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=57789c01), which is the largest boat hull LEGO has made.

Comment: Which brings us to the question whether you can build boat hulls, i.e. water tight structures, out of non-boat parts!

Comment: @Aziraphale I tried once. Water is quite good at leaking between cracks. You could maybe connect multiple pieces that float on their own (some LEGO boat hulls are made this way).

Comment: I just found a very good question about the topic here: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/78/6498

Comment: You can make bigger boats that float using the boat hull segments LEGO made back in the eighties. Theoretically boats can be any size using those pieces (multiple of 8 studs I believe, as that is how long each segment is)